# Find "nth" value in BST (C)

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, traversal

I have no idea how to go about this problem.

returns pointer to NAME_VAL pair which is the
nth entry in the sorted sequence.

if i=1, you return the min entry

if i=n, you return the max entry

if n=n/2 you return the median entry (or close)

if(i < 1 || i > n) return NULL;

The runtime has to be O(log n)

Can someone point me in the right direction on the basic idea of tackling this problem? Thank you!

My structures:

```
typedef struct name_val 
{
    char *name;
    double value;
}NAME_VAL;

typedef struct node
{
    NAME_VAL *nV;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}NODE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tree is perfectly balanced (with any necessary imbalance limited to the end of the sequence), you can do this by using the bit pattern for n's binary representation to guide the walk down the nodes.  Since you're only asking for general guidance, I'll leave it at that rather than provide code.

If the tree is not perfectly balanced, you have to perform an O(n) depth first walk.  Or add an index (which has its own cost of maintenance).

Answer (score 0):

Where is the smallest element in a BST? It is the leftmost node with no left child. So follow left links until you hit NULL and that's your first element. Runtime is O(log n) if your tree is (more or less) balanced, in worst-case (a completely left leaning tree) is O(n). Similarly, the largest element is in the right-most node with no right child.

The median is the element which is in the middle, ie have the same number of elements to the left and the right of it. Unless your node is annotated with the number of children I can't see a way to implement the median in O(log n). CLRS: Introduction to Algorithms will give you the full account.